# Storing data on a DOM Event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, event-propagation

In my use case I have many events occurring at the same time, and each event has different ways of being handled.

Due to event bubbling sometimes it is necessary to ignore specific events (not executing the callback handler) because that event was already handled.

Sometimes you can not simply stop propagation of the event without breaking something else.

For the above reasons I have tried to set a custom flag or data on the event object. For example after it had been handled setting `event.handlerExecuted = true`. However I found this way of doing it to work inconsistently, and it is basically a hack.

I also want to avoid using global flags or storing references to event objects somewhere..

Some events behave like `mousedown -> mouseup -> click` each of these "steps" represents a different event, so altering the `mousedown` event does not guarantee you still have that data available on the `click` event object.

Is there a proper way of dealing with this problem?